# Can console app use Process.StandaardInput against WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I want to send data from a console exe, code below, to a WPF app. The test wpf exe has 3 input text boxes. But the following code, straight from online examples, and which seems very simple, does not fill out the first text box on the form - it remains blank. Does WPF accept StandardInput?

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "C:\\temp\\testWPF.exe";
info.CreateNoWindow = false;   
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
//info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello World");
p.StandardInput.Flush();
```

Comment: _"Does WPF accept StandardInput?"_ - yes, but StandardInput does not do what you expect it to. Please explain what problem exactly you're trying to solve by letting one program write in another program's UI controls.

Comment: So what do you do in wpf app to fill textbox from standard input?

Comment: What you want is not standad input/output but execution parameters, pass the values as parameters to the app and then retrieve them on the Main function, it's up to you how to fill the textboxes with the data.

Comment: CodeCaster: this is a learning exercise. I wanted to know if the Process class could be used to write a unit testing/regression testing program against wpf. Yes, I know there are dozens of those apps available - I saw one just last Friday. But I'd like to know how they do what they do.

Comment: Evk: yes, fill a wpf textbox from another console app.

Comment: Gusman: assume there is no access to the source code for the wpf app. Also, would like to know more about 'not standard input/output'. All the examples say StandardInput replaces the keyboard input for the app.

Comment: So you are doing nothing to fill textbox in WPF app as I understand (I mean you did not write any code in WPF application to handle the input). This is not how it works and it's not possible to fill inputs of arbitrary wpf application this way. Standard input is in simple terms from what you read with Console.ReadLine and similar functions. You don't read that input in wpf app, so nothing happens.

Comment: I think to do what you want, you would need to use `SendMessage` to send text to the `TextBox`.  And to do that you would need to find out the handle to the `TextBox`'s window.  I'm not 100% certain it's the same for WPF as it is for WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does WPF accept StandardInput?

Not normally, no. That is, every Windows process can in fact support the standard I/O streams, but GUI programs don't generally *do* anything with them. They will receive input via window messages instead. So unless you're dealing with an odd-ball WPF program that has added support explicitly for the standard I/O streams, using `Process.StandardInput` isn't going to work. You can write to the stream, but no one is listening.

More likely, you want to use one of the several inter-process automation schemes. The most rudimentary approach would be to use one of the low-level message-sending APIs, e.g. [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) (I wouldn't use the native `SendMessage()` function…it's too low-level and will require a lot of fiddling to get to work correctly, because you're interacting directly at the individual control window handle level).

A more robust mechanism would be [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx). This is available via .NET through the [System.Windows.Automation namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx).